# Data removed in background causes index out of range crash in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, realm

### Code

```
var animals: Results<Animal> {
    didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

### Problem

- I have a `UITableView` that displays a list of Animals
- I also have a background process that syncs the list of Animals periodically
- The UIViewController displaying the UITableView keeps track of the Animals via a member variable.
- If the background process removes the last Animal from the Realm DB while I am viewing the list, the `animals` collection updates, but the `UITableView` doesn't know that it has lost a row, if I scroll to where the deleted Animal would have been, I receive an Index of bounds exception from Realm and the application crashes.

### Attempted solutions

1. I attempted copying the `Results<Animal>` into a `[Animal]` in memory and binding the `UITableView` to that instead, since the `Array` wouldn't auto-refresh like the `Results<Animal>` does (there's no way to turn that off right?). This got around the Index out of bounds exception, except now I receive an exception for accessing properties on a deleted/invalidated object because when the cell reads properties on the deleted object, it has to go back to Realm. Not going to work.
2. I then attempted to listen to Realm's notifications and `.reloadData` the table accordingly. This works but causes excessive table reloading and adds the overhead of making sure notification tokens are deallocated, etc, and remembering to do this across all table views in the application.

### The work around

I ended up creating a `RealmTableHandler` singleton which is basically a sooped up version of solution #2.

```
public extension UITableView {
    public func addToRealmTableHandler() {
        RealmTableHandler.sharedInstance.addTrackedTable(self)
    }
}

/// Listens for Realm Notifications and reloads tracked UITableViews if needed
public class RealmTableHandler {
    public static let sharedInstance = RealmTableHandler()

    private var notificationToken: NotificationToken!

    private var tableIdentifier = 0
    private lazy var trackedTables = NSMapTable(keyOptions: NSHashTableWeakMemory, valueOptions: NSHashTableWeakMemory)
    private lazy var trackedDelegates = NSMapTable(keyOptions: NSHashTableWeakMemory, valueOptions: NSHashTableWeakMemory)
    private lazy var trackedDatasources = NSMapTable(keyOptions: NSHashTableWeakMemory, valueOptions: NSHashTableWeakMemory)

    private init() {
        self.startListening()
    }

    private func startListening() {
        self.notificationToken = Realm().addNotificationBlock { (notification, realm) -> Void in
            self.checkTrackedTables()
        }
    }

    public func addTrackedTable(table: UITableView) {
        if self.trackedTables.count == 0 {
            self.tableIdentifier = 0
        }

        if let delegate = table.delegate, datasource = table.dataSource {
            self.tableIdentifier++

            self.trackedTables.setObject(table, forKey: self.tableIdentifier)
            self.trackedDelegates.setObject(delegate, forKey: self.tableIdentifier)
            self.trackedDatasources.setObject(datasource, forKey: self.tableIdentifier)
        }
    }

    private func checkTrackedTables() {
        // Ensure table, delegate, datasource are all available, sometimes the delegate or datasource are deallocated before the table, but the table keeps a reference to them
        for key in self.trackedTables.keyEnumerator().allObjects {
            if let table = self.trackedTables.objectForKey(key) as? UITableView,
                delegate = self.trackedDelegates.objectForKey(key) as? UITableViewDelegate,
                datasource = self.trackedDatasources.objectForKey(key) as? UITableViewDataSource
            {
                // Check if tracked tables need to be reloaded due to Realm data changes
                let numSectionsInTableView = table.numberOfSections()
                var numRowsInTableView = 0
                let numSectionsInDatasource = datasource.numberOfSectionsInTableView?(table) ?? numSectionsInTableView
                var numRowsInDatasource = 0

                if numSectionsInTableView <= 0 || numSectionsInDatasource <= 0 {
                    return
                }

                for i in 0...(numSectionsInTableView - 1) {
                    numRowsInTableView += table.numberOfRowsInSection(i)
                }
                for i in 0...(numSectionsInDatasource - 1) {
                    numRowsInDatasource += datasource.tableView(table, numberOfRowsInSection: i)
                }

                if numRowsInTableView != numRowsInDatasource {
                    table.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then add the following code to any `UITableViews` I want to be reloaded if Realm increases or decreases the amount of their rows.

```
self.tableView.addToRealmTableHandler()
```

This seems to work fine, even with sectioned `UITableViews` (as long as the sectionized data is also `Results<T>`).

Is there a better/simpler approach to working around this problem?

Will Realm support table insertion/deletion in the future?

Comment: Instead of ReloadData you can add, remove, move, or reload single rows with reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, addRowsAtIndexPaths, removeRowsAtIndexPaths, deleteRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: Ya. I wanted a global generic solution though. Which wouldn't know which row indexes were affected.

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer: I work for Realm.)*

Hrmm, it sounds like you want something similar to a `NSFetchedResultsController` from Core Data, where you get a generic-level, yet fine-grained set of notifications when objects are added/deleted.

I'm not sure if this will do the trick in your case, but there's actually an open-source library designed to do just that with Realm named `RBQFetchedResultsController` (https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQFetchedResultsController). At the very least, this should help save you from trying to create a custom solution on your own. :)

Let me know if that solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Unfortunately we don't have time left for R&D so our workaround will have to do for now. I'll look into it at some point though! Are you guys working on support for this natively in Realm?

Comment: No worries! Yes! We're working on a natively-integrated solution, but we haven't got a projected release date for it yet (Hence why I didn't mention it here).